# Image Radio Button Checked Display Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using image radio buttons which are working fine. However one of the radio buttons needs to be checked by default. However when this is set, it will not display the border around the checked image as it will when you click to select.

I have tried quite a few different things such has checked via html as well as `javascript onload` to no avail.

(Note there is only one radio button to select, this is because currently there is no 2nd option however there will be in the near future hence why we are pre checking it)

Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a.radio-color-picture").click(function(){
            var $id = $(this).attr('id');
            $("a.radio-color-picture").removeClass('radio-color-border');
            $("a#" + $id).addClass('radio-color-border');
        });
    });
    function set_radio($inputid) {
        $("input#" + $inputid).click();
    }
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    a.radio-color-picture {
        border: 2px solid transparent;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 160px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
        width: 160px;
    }
    a.radio-color-picture:hover {
        border:2px solid #d13a7a;
    }
    a.radio-color-border {
        border:5px solid #d13a7a;
    }
    a#color {
        background: url("<?php echo get_bloginfo('wpurl');?>/wp-content/themes/Impreza/_customimages/thumbnail.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    }
    .hidden {
        left: -10000px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -1000px;
    }
</style>
<input type="radio" value="CHAR" name="color" id="color" class="hidden" checked="checked" />
<a id="color" href="javascript:set_radio('color');" class="radio-color-picture">&nbsp;</a>
```

Cheers :)

Comment: The problem is you are only running the function when a button is clicked. You need to trigger it both when one is clicked and on page load.

Comment: is this is your result http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/1794/  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could actually be done much simpler :

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gq57e/)**

Javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.radio-color-picture').click(function(){
        $(this).prev('input.hidden').click();
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML (make sure you use unique ids !)

```
<input type="radio" value="CHAR" name="color" id="color" class="hidden" />
<a data-idinput="color" id="link" class="radio-color-picture">&nbsp;</a>
<input type="radio" value="CHAR2" name="color" id="color2" class="hidden" checked="checked" />
<a data-idinput="color2" id="link2" class="radio-color-picture">&nbsp;</a>
<input type="radio" value="CHAR3" name="color" id="color3" class="hidden" />
<a data-idinput="color3" id="link3" class="radio-color-picture">&nbsp;</a>
```

And this is the main trick in CSS (only for IE >= 9) :

```
input.hidden:checked + a {
    border:5px solid #d13a7a;
}
```

Edit : [Demo for older versions of IE compatibility](http://jsfiddle.net/PggG4/)

Comment: Cheers mate, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

to show the css to default checked you have to add the css 'class' or 'id' by default to the pre checked radio button and its respective href tag.